# Split semicolon file into arrays, something strange

Tags: java, arrays

I want to split a word string so that every word is split with a semicolon into an array.

Why is the length of this string just 2? How can I make the length of the array to always bee 6, because every line in my file is separated into 6 fields separated by a semicolon. And a fixed length of a array will make it much easier to create a object.

```
String line = "Name;Phone;;;;;";
String parts[] = line.split(";");
```

In this case the length of parts will be 2.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to use

```
String parts[] = line.split(";",6);
```

As you can see from the [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String,%20int%29) you can enforce a limit on the split method.

Comment: but this doesn't force the array to a size of 6, it only limits it.

Comment: @Jon True. But, if it is always 6 fields separated by semicolons like the question states the result will always be a length of 6.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using [Apache StringUtils](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-2.5/org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils.html).

Specifically, I would use one of the following two methods:

```
splitPreserveAllTokens(String str, String separatorChars) 
splitPreserveAllTokens(String str, String separatorChars, int max)
```

These methods will preserve empty tokens in your array. The second one will force your result to have a maximum size (6, for example), but could cause your final token to contain delimiters, if the number of words exceeded the limit.

Comment: `Scanner`s are easier to use, and are expandable if he wants to process each one differently (e.g. my answer). I won't vote down, since this works, but I don't think its the nicest way to do this.

Comment: @Jon I'll argue that `Scanner` is not "easier to use". `String[] myArray = StringUtils.splitPreserveAllTokens("Name;Phone;;;;;", ";");` is pretty simple. If the input always contains a fixed number of delimiters, this is the most elegant solution. If not, I agree that another solution may be more appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

You can declare array first like

```
  String parts[] = new string[6];
```

Answer (score 1):

The documentation of the [String.split()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29) method mention that the trailing empty string are skipped.

You may try the following to keep trailing empty strings:

```
String parts[] = line.split(";", -1);
```

Comment: it results in 7 tokens instead of 6 :)

Answer (score 1):

Try `line.split(";",-1)` instead.

Comment: This doesn't force the array to a size of 6, in fact its no different than a use without the limit.

Comment: @Jon It is different than if he were to not use a limit. If you supply a negative value as the limit empty trailing Strings are not discard. However if do not supply a limit empty trailing Strings are discarded.

Comment: The difference from the call with a single argument is that it allows empty values. In the OP's case, if there are 5 ';'s, you should end up with 6 elements.

Comment: `line.split(";",-1)` actually returns 7 elements :)

Answer (score 0):

Use [Google's Guava library](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/) it has an advanced Splitter

```
Splitter.on(';')
       .trimResults()
       .omitEmptyStrings()
       .split("Name;Phone;;;;;");
```

Comment: That's a big add-on to his program, there are easier ways.

Comment: I am sure that once he get that he'll find more uses for the lib :). And if you look at the other options offered I am not sure about easier ways